# Useful ASP.NET modules?

Tags: asp.net, module

I recently discovered ELMAH as a drop-in module for error logging for ASP.NET and am now wondering: what other killer modules do I not know about? What's your favourite/indispensible ASP.NET module/handler/whatever? (I work in ASP.NET 2.0 so please specify version compatibility!)

Comment: http://exceptioneer.com/public/whatisexceptioneer.aspx for error handling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good selection of modules at:http://www.iis.net/downloads (mostly IIS7 modules)

My favourite is probably the streaming module that limits bandwidth after an intial burst of data, optimizing the transfer of progressive downloads: http://www.iis.net/media.

As for IIS6, SAFileup was useful for allowing large file transfers by chunking files to disk rather than loading the data into memory (ISAPI Plugin + .net Module). This is a commercial product however and I think they're may be some free or cheaper alternatives now days.

There's also several dynamic image resizing modules that are extremely useful.